# How to structure a shared npm module for Angular 2/Ionic 2 apps

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing several Ionic 2 utility apps that share functionaility such as authentication services and keypad components and naturally want to separate these out into a shared module. The plan has been to use `npm link` to ease concurrent development of the shared module and the apps. However, I have run into issues when trying to build and run my Ionic app which could either be due to improper structure of my shared module or build tool config.

My shared module has a structure as follows:

```
appkit/
    src/
        components/
            Keypad.ts
            index.ts
        pipes/
            PipeA.ts
            PipeB.ts
            index.ts
        services/
            AuthenticationService.ts
            DocumentService.ts
            index.ts
        Appkit.module.ts
        index.ts

    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

Each of the index files have a similar structure for example `src/pipe/index.ts`:

```
export { PipeA } from "./PipeA";
export { PipeB } from "./PipeB";
```

And the root index `src/index.ts`:

```
export * from "./Appkit.module";
export * from "./components";
export * from "./pipes";
export * from "./services";
```

Where I define the Angular 2 module in `src/Appkit.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicModule } from "ionic-angular";
// Components
import { Keypad } from "./components/Keypad";

// Pipes
import { PipeA } from "./pipes/PipeA";
import { PipeB } from "./pipes/PipeB";

// Services
import { AuthenticationService } from "./services/AuthenticationService";
import { DocumentService } from "./services/DocumentService";

@NgModule({
    imports: [IonicModule],
    declarations: [
        // Components
        Keypad,
        // Pipes
        PipeA,
        PipeB
    ],
    exports: [
        // Components
        Keypad,
        // Pipes
        PipeA,
        PipeB
    ]
})
export class Appkit {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: Appkit,
            providers: [
                AuthenticationService,
                DocumentService
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

As part of the build process I copy the entire src directory to `dist/` and the run ngc which appears to do all the proper AoT compilation.

Now if I go to one of Ionic 2 app run `npm link app-kit` and then in `src/app/app.module.ts` add `Appkit.forRoot()` to the imports section and `npm run build` I get:

```
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'
```

Web pack (npm run watch) manages to get through the build but produces the same error at runtime.

I also tried physically copying the shared module folder to check if it was an issue with symlinks and get the same result.

If I use providers in the NgModule config instead of using the `forRoot()` method I get the error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'Appkit' imported by the module 'AppModule'
```

I'm not sure where exactly I am going wrong as my structure seems consistent with other angular 2 libraries.

Comment: (1) Are you using a version of angular2 in your library that is older than the one you use in your app?  I've gotten this same error when that was the problem.

(2) Also, make sure that *.metadata.json files are actually present in your node_modules folder.

(3) A third thing to try is to manually copy over the library package (or run `npm pack`) and reference the created *.tgz file in your app's package.json.  Sometimes npm link doesn't work the way I'd expect it to.

Comment: Hi @Isaac I had a quick check and (1) My angular 2 versions are identical in the library I have them listed as both peer and dev dependencies. (2) the *.metadata.json files are present in the the node_modules/appkit/dist directory, do they need to be in the root of appkit? (3) I have tried npm link, copying the directory over and npm pack and all give the same results.

Comment: *.metadata.json files need to be in the same directory as the *.ts files they reference.  I'm out of ideas without having a way to look at your code.  If you could share a git repo, I can take a look.

Comment: @Isaac, thanks I appreciate you having a look.I have created a git repo https://github.com/cubicleWar/appkit

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and so far have been unable to figure out why it's not working. I have tried using a pre-canned template which produces the same error: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-module-template

Comment: @YermoLamers I have tried the ionic2-module-template as well to no avail, it all works if I just copy ./src to the ionic app src folder and import the Appkit module though. Perhaps its an issue with the pouchdb dependency in my Appkit module.

Comment: @cubiclewar my understanding is that it has to do with an Angular 2/Ionic 2 issue with how webpack works. It is supposed to be fixed at some point. For the moment, I am doing the same thing, just checking out my module from git into a src sub-directory under my project.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after a few modifications.

1. In your readme, you're importing from `nucleus-appkit`, but the package is named `appkit`.
2. I couldn't import directly from the root, I had to import from the `dist` folder.  e.g.

`import { Appkit } from 'appkit/dist';`

3. You shouldn't include `*.ts` files in your published package.  For that matter, `*.ngfactory.ts` files shouldn't be included either but they didn't cause any errors when I left them in.  The files you want are: `*.js`, `*.js.map` and `*.metadata.json`.

After making sure to add your dependencies and peerDependencies to my app's package.json, the app compiled.

Comment: The nucleus-appkit is the actual name I just simplified it to appkit in the example repo. After adding /dist to the import VS Code now longer flags it as an error but I still get Error: Unexpected value 'Appkit' imported by the module 'AppModule'. I also tried on a fresh ionic install with the same result.